# CSS background color and text change with jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, css

Having trouble with a piece of code to change both the background color and text color when a link is clicked.....

```
<div id="main_nav">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">My Account</a></li>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Available Times</a></li>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Completed Jobs</a></li>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">New Jobs [<span class="menu_count2"></span>]</a></li>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Todays Jobs [<span class="menu_count"></span>]</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the jquery....

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab1', function(){
    $('.tab1').css({'background-color' : '#5B1762'});
    $('.tab1 a').css({'color' : '#fff'});
    $(this, '.tab1').css({'background-color': '#ccc'});
    $(this, '.tab1 a').css({'color': 'red'});
});
```

This changes the background color but the text remains white as in the css file.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, what is happening and what do you expect to happen ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are coding `$(context, selector)` instead of  the `$(selector, context)`, change:

```
$(this, '.tab1').css({'background-color': '#ccc'});
$(this, '.tab1 a').css({'color': 'red'});
```

To:

```
$(this).css({'background-color': '#ccc'});
$('a', this).css({'color': 'red'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be done that way too:

```
$('.tab1').click( function(){
    $('.tab1').css({'background-color' : '#5B1762'}).find('a').css({'color' : '#fff'});
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#ccc'}).find('a').css({'color': 'red'});
});
```